# A task with html and css to create page layout(beginner)

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am given a challenge to create a full layout of a page. I want to fill all the empty spaces inbetween my layout colors, I am using grid but can't fully span the navbar, for example, to take up the entire space on top of the browser. There is some margin I can not override on top.

I have tried using grid-template-column: 1/5 and etc but I'm confused.   The images are below

```css
html,
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-col height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.zone {
  padding: 30px 50px;
  margin: 40px 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.zone:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
  -o-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
}


/*https://paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-shiny-css-buttons*/


/***********************************************************************
         *  Green Background
         **********************************************************************/

.green {
  background: #56B870;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #56B870), color-stop(100%, #a5c956));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%);
  /* W3C */
}


/***********************************************************************
         *  Red Background
         **********************************************************************/

.red {
  background: #C655BE;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #C655BE), color-stop(100%, #cf0404));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%);
  /* W3C */
}


/***********************************************************************
         *  Yellow Background
         **********************************************************************/

.yellow {
  background: #F3AAAA;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #F3AAAA), color-stop(100%, #febf04));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%);
  /* W3C */
}


/***********************************************************************
         *  Blue Background
         **********************************************************************/

.blue {
  background: #7abcff;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #7abcff), color-stop(44%, #60abf8), color-stop(100%, #4096ee));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%);
  /* W3C */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Layout Master</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="zone green">Header</div>
  <div class="zone red">Cover</div>
  <div class="zone blue">Project Grid</div>
  <div class="zone yellow">Footer</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I need all your code. Copy him to any sandbox or code snippet. If you didn't need white spaces, try to remove`height:100%;` from `body`

Comment: Yes, please don't post pictures of code; post the actual code in a code block or a runnable snippet.

Comment: is it visible now? sorry i have just now registered

Comment: Include some HTML as well as your CSS so we have a visual output.

Comment: done :D im tilted damn

Comment: so no one can help me ? (

Comment: @TEhubSLV do you have any output pic ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your question but I will try to be helpful.
If you have some spacing on top of your page make sure that you are reset browser default styling.
for example, the body has

```
body{ 
 display: block;
 margin: 8px;
}
```

full list of  [CSS default values](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)

also, you can use some CSS normalize like [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/)

and one more helpful link is CSS grid layouts examples [grid layouts](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/)

and about height and width. CSS has units like 
vw , vh for set current browser viewport. 
[What are viewport units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)